# How do I append contents from fileA.txt to fileB.txt?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, filesystems, cat

I am trying to take updated contents from fileA.txt to update fileB.txt's information. I have already tried appending contents from fileA.txt to fileB.txt using the command,

"cat /root/important/usefulcmds >> /home/ftpuser/rootfiles/usefulcmds."

I get no error and nothing gets updated in the /rootfiles/usefulcmds file. Ultimately I want to be able to run a script that updates fileB.txt, using fileA.txt. How do I go about updating fileB.txt's information with fileA.txt's information? i.e. what command(s) do I need to use?

Thank you.

Comment: The command you show does append the first file to the second.  Your problem is probably with the filename, especially since you talk about `/rootfiles/usefulcmds` and `/home/ftpuser/rootfiles/usefulcmds.` which could be completely different.  Do note that the trailing `.` (dot) is part of the filename.

Comment: I'm sorry, when I said /rootfiles/usefulcmds I was really meaning /home/ftpuser/rootfiles/usefulcmds. the (dot) at the end of the name "usefulcmds." is just a period completing my sentence.

Comment: Then it does append it.  So look at the source to see if it actually includes what you want to append.

Comment: So I checked the source. I now have found 5 different updates to that file..the problem was that I did not scroll down far enough to see it. Talk about looking too deep down the rabbit hole. Thanks a lot Julie Pelletier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using the right command, and by the sounds of the latest comments, it works.